# Add Border to Javascript Generated Table

Tags: javascript

I converted a google spreadsheet to an HTML table using [sheetstotables.com](http://sheetstotables.com/). I now have the table on my webpage, but there is no border. How could I add a border? Here is the code:

```
<div class="sheetstotables"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableId = "ZV20A"
var x = document.createElement("script"); x.type = "text/javascript"; x.async = true;
x.src = "http://www.sheetstotables.com/get_table.js";
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(x, s);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<style>` tag to your HTML, like so:

```
<style>
    .sheetstotables {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

Or just edit the inline `style` attribute of your `<div>`:

```
<div class="sheetstotables" style="border: 2px solid red;"></div>
```

Give that a go